# Gráficar a partir de un sp c# (proyecto WEB)

Tags: c#, sql

Que tal a todos, tengo un sp que me crea esta salida de consulta:

```
CeEmplazamiento Totales
    Irapuato    150
    Celaya      115
    Coecillo    94
  Oriente León  90
   León Sur     38
```

Lo que requiero es que estos datos, los pueda gráficar a partir de un chart, es importante mencionarles que este es un proyecto WEB en C#, ya me imprime la gráfica, pero, no he podido lograr que la gráfica se llene con los datos de la consulta. Agrego el código que llevo hasta el momento. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace SistemaDashBoardFEMSA
{
    public partial class Graficas : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    int[] barras = new int[3];

    string[] nombs = new string[3];


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObtenerDatos();
    }


    //get data
    protected void ObtenerDatos()
    {
        DataSet resultado = new DataSet();

        clsConexioncs conexion_server = new clsConexioncs();

        conexion_server.Conexion = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultDW"].ToString();


        conexion_server.PreparaComandoSP("sp_telemtria_femsa");

        resultado = conexion_server.EjecutaComandoDataSet();




        foreach (DataRow row in resultado.Tables[0].Rows)
        {


        }

        Graficas_Semanal.Series["Series"].Points.DataBindXY(nombs, barras);

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar gráficos estadísticos en ASP.NET te recomiendo utilizar esta librería: https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/ . Una vez hayas instalado esta libreria en tu proyecto, lo puedes utilizar de esta forma (Este es un ejemplo para graficar un pie chart) Primero en tu lado cliente agregar esto donde quieres que aparezca el gráfico:

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrChart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Luego, en el lado del servidor:

```
            var bgColor = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.BackColorOrGradient(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
            DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts piechart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("pie")
            .InitChart(new Chart
            {
                BackgroundColor = bgColor
            })
            .SetTitle(new Title
            {
                Text = ""
            })
            .SetSeries(new Series[]
            {
           new Series()
             {
               Type = ChartTypes.Pie,
               Name = "ddd",
               Data = new Data(new object [] {
                   new object [] { "Acceso a Personas con Discapacidad",dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()},
                   new object [] { "Acceso a Internet",dt.Rows[0][1].ToString() },
                   new object [] { "Sala Multimedia",dt.Rows[0][2].ToString() },
                   new object [] { "Sala Cómputo",dt.Rows[0][3].ToString() },
                   new object [] { "Catálogo en línea", dt.Rows[0][4].ToString() }
               }),
             },
            })
            .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
            {
                Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                {
                    ShowInLegend = true,
                    AllowPointSelect = true,
                    DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                    {
                        Enabled = false
                    // Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; }"
                }
                }
            })
            .SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.y; }" });
            ltrChart1.Text = piechart.ToHtmlString();
```

Nota que estoy llenando el gráfico con un Datatable que previamente he llenado con una consulta de base de datos.
Espero te ayude esto.
Al final, tendrás esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]